# myItem.Id, is this unique across systems

Tags: c#, api, exchangewebservices

I am using the piece of C# code in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633693(v%3Dexchg.80)) link to access my Exchange 2010 server via EWS API 2.0. Now we are migrating the mailbox to the cloud and all the emails in the inbox and subfolders with it.

My question is when that happens will the `myItem.Id` value still remain the same for each and every email? The Exchange admin says it will be unique across the Exchange servers. But I found no evidence of it from the tests I have I done so far. These emails get fed into a database and when the mailbox is migrated to the cloud, the application that processes these emails will see them as new emails due to `myItem.Id` being not unique across both systems due to the migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is when that happens will the myItem.Id value still remain the same for each and every email?

No it won't, if the message is just moved between folder the Id will change. The EWSid is based on the underlying Exchange LongTermId https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxcdata/8796d8f9-0052-4a5a-ab8e-e780b9c8a6bb. So it contains both FolderId and MessageId information (there is a global counter value involved) and some EWS specific flags . Its essentially a locator so it needs to be globally unique but in Office365 the underlying Store information changes (which affects the FolderId part of this id) so the ewsId will also change. Office365 offers immutableid's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id but you need to using the Graph API they didn't backport them to EWS.

For your migration you might want to consider creating your own custom property on items so you can still find them after the migration using a Search (or use an existing property like InternetMessageId or PidtagSearchkey)

Comment: To give you some historical context of the issue.. Prior to my attempt at reading these emails via the C# API, the sqlserver proc. xp_readmail's msg_id(which is message_number, varchar(255) value) was used which was the original value in the DB I mentioned above.  Now with my approach to do the same via the C# API, I can't find any relationship between the @msg_id and the values returned by the API for the message id/item id. Any idea if there is an equivalent value from C# API that matches the xp_readmail's msg_id?

Comment: I think xp_readmail is probably using PidTagEntryId https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagentryid-canonical-property so you will need to use ConvertId in EWS to convert that to a EWSId

Comment: Thanks for your answer Glen. It really helped me.